# Applescript - move files to folders dependign on folders name

Tags: automation, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I need a generic script for Applescript which does the following:
i have a bunch of files and folders in a folder.
Folders are names lets say 10 11 12 125 126
Files have in the start of name folders name but then they have addon ie 10_XXX 11_XXX 125_XXX

Now after running a script id like files that have folders name to be moved to right folder.
The file always has [foldername]_ but sometimes the files have [foldername]_ZZZ_ZZZ so only 1st of the _ is actually about folder.

Hope i am clear.

Script id liek to be generic [as working on the folder that i open in finder].

This script is really over my head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a shell command like this:

`for f in *; do [[ -f $f ]] || continue; d=${f##*/}; echo mv "$f" "${d%%_*}"; done`

- `[[ -f $f ]]` tests if $f is a file
- `${f##*/}` removes the longest `*/` pattern from the start
- `${d%%_*}` removes the longest `_*` pattern from the end
- Remove `echo` to actually move the files

Comment: so it shoul go trought shell not applescript? i will have a test of this.